# How to obtain DPI equivalent of an adjustable column with no text in OpenXML

Tags: c#, openxml

I would like to ask what units does column.width return when using Openxml? (IS it in EMU, metres, cm or dpi and how do i get its DPI equivalent?

Comment: Have you seen this? http://polymathprogrammer.com/2010/01/18/calculating-column-widths-in-excel-open-xml/

Comment: Yes I have seen this but it does not answer my question. And I have a template which does not have words in it that I am supposed to clone from and the column size of the template can be adjusted even without it having words in it so how can i calculate the size of each column in that template?

Answer (score 0):

From *SpreadsheetOpenXmlFromScratch*:

> Note that the width of the digits depends on the font and the font size used. I'll be using the MeasureString() function of the Graphics class to measure pixel width.

Everything Vincent does is based on the font type and size. You will have to retrieve the font type and font size to run through the calculations.

EDIT: pp 40-50

Comment: Yes but my column does not have any words so this formula is not applicable right? Furthermore, if we adjust the column width in my template the column width will vary so how do I obtain the width of the column since it has no words in it and it can be manually adjusted in the template?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is using the font measurements, not the column text. Another excerpt:

> Note that the width of the digits depends on the font and the font size used. I'll be using the MeasureString() function of the Graphics class to measure pixel width.

```
System.Drawing.Font drawfont = new System.Drawing.Font("Calibri", 11, FontStyle.Regular);
// I just need a Graphics object. Any reasonable bitmap size will do.
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(new Bitmap(256, 256));

Dim drawfont As New System.Drawing.Font("Calibri", 11, FontStyle.Regular)
' I just need a Graphics object. Any reasonable bitmap size will do.
Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(New Bitmap(256, 256))
```

> The font used should be the same as that used in your stylesheet. Otherwise you would be measuring for one font or font size, but using another font or font size to render your actual text in the Excel cell. I know it's obvious, but it's important to state here.
>
> Specifically, it should be the font used in the **Normal** style. That word is capitalised for a reason. It refers to the cell style named **Normal** (together with "Good", "Bad" and "Neutral"). Get your friendly neighbourhood Excel geek to help you find the cell style option in Excel.

Some of his other methods do require text when he actually measures the width of a zero flanked by two underscores, then subtracts the width of the underscores to get a more accurate width, but this just requires the font name and style.

> Now the MeasureString() function has a tiny problem. This is from the official documentation:
>   *The MeasureString method is designed for use with individual strings and includes a small amount of extra space before and after the string to allow for overhanging glyphs.*
>   What this means is that the following code will not exactly give you the pixel width of "0":

```
fWidthOfZero = (double)g.MeasureString("0", drawfont).Width;

fWidthOfZero = Convert.ToDouble(g.MeasureString("0", drawfont).Width)
```

Give it a try.

Comment: sadly does not seem to work. My image only covers half the column